# onFocus() for Salesforce Classic not triggered

Tags: javascript, console, salesforce-classic

Here is the document https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_onfocus.htm

The method is supposed to add a listener to call when the browser focus changes. However, it never gets call when I switch between tabs in the console.

Here is my js code

```
var callback = function (response) {
    if (response.result) {
        alert(response.result);
}};
sforce.interaction.onFocus(callback);
```

Comment: provide your full code here

Comment: That code will only run within the context of the window it was called in. It won't be active when you change tabs if you're referring to a different browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `sforce.interaction.onFocus(callback);` code?

You need to call `sforce.interaction.onFocus(callback);` as mentioned in the docs link you provided.